# How to have more than one video preview in premiere pro?

Tags: premiere, video-editor

So I want to have two different "Perspectives" in premiere pro. But so far on the internet I only found multi-cam editing. This won't work cause it's not a camera it's me and my friend playing games so I want to have his perspective of the game and mine at the same time so I can edit it.

I've attempted multi-cam either way. Didn't work since you can only select one camera at a time. What I want is having two different videos playing at the same time, But I don't want to crop the clips in order to fit another clip in since if I were to add effects I will also have to reposition them and resize them accordingly.

Comment: Can you explain the outcome you want to see on the screen? If you don’t want to cut between two clips and you don’t want to crop two clips on screen at once, how do you propose to show them?

Comment: I am trying to edit two clips at once. Kinda like mult icam. But it's my recording and my friend's recording. Multi cam wouldn't work cuz it need syncing or I'll only play one clip at once in multi cam

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

1)
If the two clips are approximately in sync, you could import them both into a multi-cam sequence, then switch between "cameras" to switch between the two recordings.  This is probably the best method. If you need to tweak the sync manually before you start switching, then open the multicam sequence in the timeline first, by right-clicking the multicam clip and choose "[open in timeline](https://community.adobe.com/t5/premiere-pro-discussions/how-to-have-two-open-timelines-in-the-same-project/td-p/10964044)"

2)
Edit the conventional way - open the clips one by one in the clip editor, select the in/out points using <kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>O</kbd> of each clip, then insert or overlay that clip into your sequence using <kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>,</kbd>

3)
[Open two timelines at the same time](https://community.adobe.com/t5/premiere-pro-discussions/how-to-have-two-open-timelines-in-the-same-project/td-p/10964044), and cut clips out of one and overlay/insert them into the other using [Lift and Extract](https://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/lift-extract-premiere-pro/) (usually <kbd>;</kbd> and <kbd>'</kbd>) then paste the clip into the other sequence.

Comment: Thanks I will try the methods. will mark as answer if it works.